# WordPress saves posts in wrong timezone

Tags: wordpress, timezone

Whenever I try to save a post in the future, the time will detract 2 hours. This seems to be a timezone issue, but I cannot figure out what causes this.

My server timezone is set to Europe/Amsterdam, as well as my WordPress timezone.

If I want to save a post for 18:00 today, it gets saved as 16:00.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where to look?

Answer (score 0):

What time zone are you in? Does it happen to be 2 hours apart?

Comment: This should be a comment